# What's wrong with my answer to this constraint satisfaction problem, which needs to be solved the AC-3 algorithm?

Tags: constraint-satisfaction-problems, homework

I was watching the video [Constraint Satisfaction: the AC-3 algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cCS8rrYT14), and I tried to solve this question:

> Given the variables A, B, C and D, with domain {1, 2, 3, 4} in each of them and restrictions A> B, B = C and D ≠ A, use the AC algorithm.

But the teacher told me that my answer below is wrong!

He gave me a tip: Domain D will not be changed!

Below, I is my answer step by step. If someone can help me find the error, I appreciate it!

To solve this exercise, it is first necessary to organize the data in order to separate what is the domain, agenda and arc.

[image: Step 1]

Soon after, we will analyze the first item on the agenda “A> B” with domain A, in order to eliminate unnecessary elements from the domain.

[image: step 2.]

Analyze domain B with the agenda item “B <A”

[image: 3 step]

Analyze domain B with the agenda item “B = C” and add the constraint “A> B”

[image: 4 Step]

Analyze domain D with the agenda item “D ≠ A” and add the constraint “B <A”

[image: 5 Step]

Analyze domain A with the agenda item “A ≠ D”

[image: 6 Step]

Analyze domain A with the agenda item “A> B”

[image: 7 Step]

Analyze domain B with the agenda item “B = C”

[image: 8 Step]

Analyze domain B with the agenda item “B <A”

[image: 9 Step]

Result

[image: 10 Step]

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy $D\ne A$, for each element in the domain of $D$, say $d$, there must be at least one element in the domain of $A$, say $a$, that $d \ne a$.

Domain of $D$: $ \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \} $

Domain of $A$: $ \{ 2, 3, 4 \} $

So, for example if $d=2$, there is at least one element in the domain of $A$ like $a$ such that $d \ne\ a$. E.g. $1, 3$ and $4$.
So, $2$ remains in the domain of $D$. This is the case for other elements of $D$.